# How to use base images on Github Actions build script?

Tags: mongodb, github-actions

Creating pipeline for GitHub Actions, which is a great feature. A few questions

1) Which images are available for use in the build? Can I use one of my public Docker Hub images as a base image so that I can spare myself installing the linux dependencies and gems?

2) How can I configure MongoDB as a service? Is there an image available for that?

main.yaml below:

```
name: CI
on: [pull_request]
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      db:
        image: postgres:11
        ports: ['5432:5432']
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Setup Ruby
        uses: actions/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: 2.5.5
      - name: Build and run tests
        env:
          DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:@localhost:5432/test
          RAILS_MASTER_KEY: ${{ secrets.RAILS_MASTER_KEY }}
        run: |
          sudo sed -i 's/none/read|write/g' /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
          wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.6.asc | sudo apt-key add -
          echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org mongodb-org-server
          sudo systemctl start mongod
          sudo apt-get -yqq install libpq-dev
          wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
          RELEASE=$(lsb_release -cs)
          echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ ${RELEASE}"-pgdg main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
          cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
          sudo apt update
          sudo apt -y install postgresql-11
          sudo apt-get install build-essential supervisor nodejs libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev tidy ghostscript less ffmpeg imagemagick -y
          gem install -N bundler -v 1.17.3
          gem install -N nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
          cp vendor/platform/phantomjs-*-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 /tmp
          sudo tar -C /usr/local/bin --strip-components=2 --wildcards -xvjf /tmp/phantomjs-*-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 phantomjs-*-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs
          bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 3
          RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:create
          bundle exec rspec
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Which images are available for use in the build? Can I use one of my public Docker Hub images as a base image so that I can spare myself installing the linux dependencies and gems?

Yes ! Feel free to use your image with the keyword **uses in your first step** like that :

```
- uses: docker://{host}/{image}:{tag}
```

> 2) How can I configure MongoDB as a service? Is there an image available for that?

You can do like that :

```
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.4.23
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

Also, there is [an article](https://dev.to/s_abderemane/how-to-use-docker-services-in-github-actions-6ce) about Docker services maybe it can helps you to better understand services in Github Actions.